# How to start emacs with a custom agenda view?

Tags: org-mode, init-file, org-agenda, todo

I can start emacs with my org-mode agenda view by putting the following in my `init.el` file:

```
(org-agenda-list)
(delete-other-windows)
```

Or I can start it with my global todo list:

```
(org-todo-list)
(delete-other-windows)
```

But not both. I can define a custom view like so:

```
(add-to-list
 'org-agenda-custom-commands
 '("z" "calendar + todo"
   ((agenda "")
    (todo ""))))
```

But how can I start emacs with this custom view loaded?

Comment: If you type `C-h f` aka `M-x describe-function`, you can look up `org-agenda-list` and see what the optional arguments are.  You can then experiment by calling that function with your custom arguments, including, but not limited to let-binding certain applicable variables ...

Comment: The arguments of `org-agenda-list` are `(&optional ARG START-DAY SPAN WITH-HOUR)`. There doesn't seem to be anything related to TODOs in there. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start it with

```
(org-agenda nil "z")
```

Read more about this function by `M-x describe-function`, org-agenda

```
(org-agenda &optional ARG ORG-KEYS RESTRICTION)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your method works just fine, it still loads the splash screen and executes an additional command which is not very efficient in my opinion. So I wanted to add this as a solution:

```lisp
(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'(lambda ()
                               (let ((org-agenda-window-setup 'only-window))
                                 (org-agenda nil "z"))))
```

This code omits the Emacs splash screen and then adds a lambda function to the the hook that is executed after Emacs has been initialized. The lambda function temporarily replaces the variable that tells org agenda how to setup its window, which makes display as the only window. Finally, org custom agenda view is called using the function mentioned by @cauchy-cai

PS: Sorry if this reply doesn't focus on the question, I wanted to comment but I don't meet the minimum required reputation to do so.